# How to get the upload progress in using Django?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, progress-bar

I would like to create an upload progress bar on a website, but I'm not sure how to retrieve the upload progress of the file or image that is uploading. How can I achieve this with Django?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is something you'll have to handle on the client-side to provide the actual progress bar, so using something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) is probably ideal here.

As it turns out, [someone had the same problem and wrote up a blog post with how they solved it using jQuery](http://www.lonelycode.com/2009/06/09/django-file-upload-progress-bar-without-flash/).  It uses [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/678/) and the [jQuery timers](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers) plugin.

Comment: The blog post is not there anymore.

Answer (score 0):

[Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/index.php) is a great javascript uploading widget.